# how to convert data selected from a postgres database to json or csv to use it with d3js lib?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, d3.js

is there any way to convert data that get from my postgresql database to csv or json, I just want to use it as input for my D3.js ! 
otherwise is it possible use it without conversion ?

this how I get data from my Database :

```js
    var pg = require("pg");

    var connectionString = {
        user: 'user',
        host: 'host',
        database: 'db',
        password: 'pass',
        port: 5432,
    };

    var pool = new pg.Pool(connectionString);
    pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
        const query = client.query(new pg.Query("SELECT * from products")), query.on('row', (row) => {
            console.log(row);
        })
        query.on('end', (res) => {
            // pool shutdown 
            console.log("ending");
            pool.end()
        })

        query.on('error', (res) => {
            console.log(res);
        })

        done()
    })
    // done
```

Comment: Can you please post the code that you're using for querying the DB?

Comment: "is there any way to convert data that get from my postgresql database to csv or json' you mean let postgresql generate csv or json data from the products table?  Provide a sqlfiddle.com with example data

Comment: I mean convert any data from a table to csv or json !

Comment: @LuigiCerone done !

Comment: isn't that variable row within that javascript code not already a json object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_to_json` and `array_to_string` in your query.

See below an example.

```
SELECT array_to_string(array( SELECT row_to_json(products.*) FROM products),', ') as jsonData;
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: one thing , we need to use `row.jsondata` not jsonData when we want to use it.